# How to make a loop of components in render method?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have a Pagination component that receives, as props from its parent, the number of page links it must render.

Let's say a company has 90 workers. In this case the Pagination component will have the number 9 as a prop (each page renders 10 workers, resulting in 9 pages, 10 workers each page).

How can I create a loop that takes the prop and loops DIV's and links according to what the prop brings?

If I create a FOR loop, it prints "[object]" in my page instead HTML.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Paginacao extends Component {
    render() {

    // This console.log() returns 9
    console.log(this.props.totalPages);

        return (
            <div>
                // A 9-cycles loop must print this:
                // <div><a href = "page1">1</a></div>
                // <div><a href = "page2">2</a></div>
                // <div><a href = "page3">3</a></div>
                // <div><a href = "page4">4</a></div>
                // <div><a href = "page5">5</a></div>
                // <div><a href = "page6">6</a></div>
                // <div><a href = "page7">7</a></div>
                // <div><a href = "page8">8</a></div>
                // <div><a href = "page9">9</a></div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Paginacao
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a for loop like so.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Paginacao extends Component {
    render() {
      const items = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < this.props.totalPages; i++) {
        items.push(<div><a href =`page${i + 1}`>{i + 1}</a></div>)
      }
     // This console.log() returns 9
    console.log(this.props.totalPages);

        return (
            <div>
               {items}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Paginacao
```

Comment: this is a very elegant and brilliant solution

Comment: Sorry I'm late. Your answer is the solution. Thanks! I used the same structure as you did. But I did like this:
let html = "";

Inside the FOR loop I did:

html += <div><a href = "`page${i + 1}`">{i + 1}</a></div>

So, the difference is I didn't use "push" but "+=" in a string. Could you explain why React returns [object] when I use string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to create array from `this.props.totalPages` number. Easiest way is

```
const pages = [];

for (let i = 1; i <= this.props.totalPages; i++) {
  pages.push(<div><a href={`page{i}`}>{i}</a></div>);
}
```

then in render method

```
return (
  <div>
    {pages}
  </div>
)
```

or more fancy style:

```
return (
  <div>
    {Array.from(Array(this.props.totalPages).keys()).map(i =>
      <div><a href={`page{i + 1}`}>{i + 1}</a></div>
    )}
  </div>
)
```

if you are using Ramda or similar lib, you can replace `Array.from(Array(this.props.totalPages).keys())` with `R.times`

Comment: That's the solution. I actually tested Chaim Friedman's solution, which is like yours. I was trying to return "pages" as a string and the print in HTML  was [object]. Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

Map an array of passing objects and map that array to a component you want to render.

Like below code:

```
<div>
  {
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].map(item => {
      return <div><a href={'page' + item + 1}>{item}</a></div>;
    })
  }
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution Ravi Sevta! I was using the return as a string instead array, which was returning [object] in my page. Could you explain why that happens?

Comment: @Raphael Alvarenga, Could you please share your current code of looping, so I can check it.

Comment: sorry... I already changed the code based on the solutions suggested here. Basically, I was populating a variable with HTML as string. Like: var html = ""; html += "<div>"; html += "<a href = 'page1'>1</a>"; html += "</div>";